# After changing name of components in react it is giving error

Tags: reactjs

when I changed name components like this Components into components then it is giving error like this :

File name

```
'/Users/nabarajrai/resturant_workshop/onlineresturantfrontend/src/client/components/common/Icons.component.jsx' differs from already included file name '/Users/nabarajrai/resturant_workshop/onlineresturantfrontend/src/client/Components/common/Icons.component.jsx' only in casing.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via "../common/Icons.component" from file '/Users/nabarajrai/resturant_workshop/onlineresturantfrontend/src/client/Components/Auth/ResturantSignUp.component.jsx'
    Imported via "../common/Icons.component" from file '/Users/nabarajrai/resturant_workshop/onlineresturantfrontend/src/client/components/Auth/Login.component.jsx'
    Imported via "../common/Icons.component" from file '/Users/nabarajrai/resturant_workshop/onlineresturantfrontend/src/client/components/Auth/RestaurantLogin.component.jsx'ts(1149)
ResturantSignUp.component.jsx(9, 8): File is included via import here.
Login.component.jsx(3, 37): File is included via import here.
```

Comment: The error message you're encountering is due to a casing difference in the file paths. In most operating systems, file paths are case-sensitive, which means that even a difference in the capitalization of letters in the file path can lead to issues when importing or referencing files. By carefully checking and updating all references and file paths, you should be able to resolve the error related to the casing difference and ensure that your code works correctly.